# Is there any VS Code extension for Code explanation?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any Visual Studio code extension for code explanation. 
The default extension gives basics information only. But I want more information regarding syntax.
It'll be great if an extension can pull information from some wiki page like wikipedia, w3schools.

[**Default syntax information**]

[image]

Comment: `len(obj) -> int` is the syntax, what more do you want from `len()`. VSC is not a python training tool.

Comment: @rioV8 haha, I don't mean that. I mean, if there is some extension that pulls the descriptions like the definition of it, basics of example, etc. I hope you get my point. If there is not, I'll be okay too. :)